# How to compute a correlation coefficient for each participant using a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create a for loop where I perform a Pearson's correlation for each individual participant between two variables over the course of 120 trials. I am aiming to compute a correlation coefficient between the two variables for each individual participant. So far, I have written some code that looks like this:

```
for (i in unique(adult_pref_1$subject)){
 a <- cor.test(adult_pref_1$own_pref, adult_pref_1$profile_rating_new) 
print(paste(colnames(adult_pref_1)[subj], " est:", a$estimate, " p=value:", a$p.value))}
```

However, when I run this code, it seems to compute the overall correlation across all participants between the two variables rather than a single value for each participant. Here's a preview of my data I am working with (I am specifically correlation each participants own_pref with profile_rating)
[image]

I am still a bit of a novice when it comes to R and am open to suggestions for improving my code. Everyone's thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput(head(mydf))` instead of a screenshot in order to reproduce and provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: Notice that the `i` variable isn't actually used anywhere inside the loop.  Inside `cor.test()`, you probably want `adult_pref_1$own_pref[adult_pref_1$subject == i]` and `adult_pref_1$profile_rating_new[adult_pref_1$subject == i]`.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have solved my problem!